# Show 'My Computer' when a textbox is clicked on my website

Tags: javascript, html, filesystems

I have an HTML/JavaScript website, and I would like to be able to use a user selected file within and be able to **upload it to the server.**

How can I open up *My Computer* on selection of a textbox?

Answer (score 2):

If you want an input for file input use something like this

```
<input type="file" name="uploadbox">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to upload the file to the server via http file input in a form. Process the file server side and then return results to the client side. Check:

http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to have more information, but here is the best advice I can think to give:
As Dominic Green said, you can use the file input to select a file. However, I'm not sure what you're wanting to use the file for.

If you're wanting it to be uploaded, then that would need to be handled on the server, which is what Miquel mentioned.

If you only want to work with it using JavaScript without needing to upload it to the server, then the File API may be of use. However, this is not widely supported through all browsers, and is a relatively new (HTML5) feature. The File API will allow you to retrieve information about a file that is selected by the user through a file input or a file that has been dropped onto the web page, as well as read the file as text or data.

For further reading about the File API, I recommend HTML5Rocks' tutorial: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/